# find minimum initial value, such that sum is always 1 or greater

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sum

Given an array of integers, find the smallest number X to start with, such that adding elements of array to X, the sum is always greater than or equal to 1

If given array is {-2, 3, 1, -5} For example, in the above array, X should be 4

Explanation: If, we start with 4, then adding first number -2, array sum becomes 4 + (-2) = 2 (which is >0) Now adding next element 3 to current sum which is 2, 2+ 3 = 5 (which is >0) Adding next element 1 to new sum 5 gives, 5 + 1 = 6 (which is >0) Adding last element -5 to new sum 6 gives 6 + (-5) = 1, which is again greater than zero.

This is my code so far, but it doesn't work:

```
function minX(arr) {
    var sum = 0
    var runningSum= 0
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if ((arr[i] + sum) <= 1){
            var diff = arr[i] + sum
            var someNumber = 1 - diff
            sum = someNumber + sum

        }
        runningSum += arr[i]
    }
  return sum
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the array first while keeping track of the lowest sum found so far. At the end, the result is the number such that adding it to the lowest sum found results in 1:

```js
const minX = (arr) => {
  let recordMin = 0;
  let sum = 0;
  for (const elm of arr) {
    sum += elm;
    recordMin = Math.min(recordMin, sum);
  }
  return -recordMin + 1;
};

console.log(minX([-2, 3, 1, -5]));
console.log(minX([-2, 3, 1, -5, 999]));
```

Comment: I see, why the need for the (-) in front of recordMin at the end?

Comment: Since the equation to solve is `recordMin + result = 1`, you get `result = 1 - recordMin` - or `result = -recordMin + 1`

Answer (score 2):

Get the total sum of the elements of the array, for example, by using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Then, negate it and add 1. So, all together:

```
function minX(arr) {
    return -arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + 1;
}
```

Or, to simplify:

```
function minX(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => a - b, 1);
}
```

Comment: I don't think a simple sum is sufficient. Take, for example, `[-2, 3, 1, -5, 999]` - output would need to be 4, not -995.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It works, if I understood the problem correctly. The function returns -995 and `-995 - 2 + 3 + 1 -5 + 999` equals 1. Why 4? -995 < 4 and OP wants the smallest number you can find.

Comment: OP wants to ensure that the cumulative sum *any any point* while iterating over the array is no less than 1 - not just the final cumulative sum after iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the wanted result and subtract all values of the array.

```js
function minX(array) {
    return array.reduce((s, v) => s - v, 1);
}

console.log(minX([-2, 3, 1, -5])); // 4
```

Comment: I don't think a simple sum is sufficient. Take, for example, `[-2, 3, 1, -5, 999]` - output would need to be 4, not -995.